# Upgrade Windows web server 2008 64 bit to Windows server 2008 R2 standard

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a server running on windows web server 2008, SP2(64 bit). I want to upgrade it to windows server 2008 R2 Standard edition.

Do I need to buy a new windows server 2008 R2 Standard edition license? I could not find anything on the Microsoft website about supported free upgrades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 is a separate license and must be purchased. You can accomplish an upgrade from Server 2008 to Server 2008 R2.

[Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-R2.aspx)

[Pricing](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/pricing.aspx)